# How to use asynchronous method in a synchronous method

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, web, synchronous

I developed a game in web technology that store the data in LocalStorage. The LocalStorage works as synchronous.To set and get the values from localstorage as

// set the value in localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('Key', "value");
```

// get the value from localstorage

```
var localValue = localStorage.getItem('Key');
```

There is 5MB limit in localstorage. After play the some level, localstorage filled completely. I need a large area for storage at client side.

My first question is that **“What is the best way to solve this problem?”**

To solve above problem,I find the [LargeLocalStorage](https://github.com/tantaman/LargeLocalStorage).It is worked as asynchronous.

// set the value in LargeLocalStorage

```
storage.setContents('docKey', "the contents...").then(function() {alert('doc created/updated');});
```

// get the value from LargeLocalStorage

```
storage.getContents('myDoc').then(function(content){//content is value for particular key});
```

Is there is any way that make these method synchronous because my all code is according to the synchronous localstorage. It will take a lot of time to change the whole logic according to the asynchronous LargeLocalStorage.

I am currently try to override the setItem and getItem method of localstorage as :

```
localStorage.__proto__.getItem = function(key) {

var returnVal;

storage.getContents(key).then(function(content) {
        returnVal = content;

    });
return returnVal;//it returns undefined
}
```

Above override method returns undefined value due to asynchronous behaviour.

Please help me to get value synchronous using above methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just continue the async chain either by using promises or using callbacks: `localStorage.__proto__.getItem = function(key, callback) {}`. Personally I would use promises for that because it solves the [**Callback Hell**](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible since you don't have thread control in javascript, so you can't have a busy loop waiting for your value to change or something like this. Having your method call a callback instead of return and doing your stuff in the callback is the way to go.

Comment: Generally you do not want to use synchronous data manipulation - its halts execution of your program completely until it is complete, and can lock up the browser completely if you aren't careful. You need to start considering asynchronous operations - think of them as a way of starting up a new thread in the background, and let it do its work. You can easily set it up where async operations look like sync operations (by using the callback to continue your code execution), but I would put serious consideration into how you can work with async operations to give your users a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, LocalStorage is quiet good, but if you want to store a lot of data, i suggest you to take a look about **[PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)**, which is a JavaScript implementation of **CouchDB**, a NoSQL database.

Pouchdb use **[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB)** as its storage mechanism. So, PouchDB runs in the browser, which provides speed.

I think that can be really helpful in your case :).

If you have time take a look about this piece of code that i've made :

**Database Class**

```
var Database = (function(){

    var instance = undefined;

    function Database(){
      //Create new database Game
      this.db = new PouchDB('Game');

      //Listen for db changes, and fired show function
      this.db.changes({
        since: 'now',
        live: true
      }).on('change', this.show);

    }

    //Show function retrieve all docs, and add it to the html
    Database.prototype.show = function(){
      this.db
      .allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true})
      .then(function(response){
        var data = response.rows;
        var preview = document.querySelector('.preview');
        while (preview.firstChild) {
            preview.removeChild(preview.firstChild);
        }
        data.forEach(function(elm){
          var p = document.createElement('p');
          p.innerHTML = elm.doc.title;
          preview.appendChild(p);
        });
      });
    }


    //Add a doc to our database
    Database.prototype.add = function(data){
      this.db
      .post(data)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log('Data added !');
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
    }

    //Clean our database
    Database.prototype.reset = function(){
      var db = this.db;
      //retrieve all docs
      db.allDocs({include_docs:true, descending: true})
        .then(function(response){
          var rows = response.rows;
          var docs = rows.map(function(elm){
            return elm.doc;
          });
          //Create promises array
          var promises = docs.map(function(elm){
            //Return promise remove
            return db.remove(elm._id, elm._rev);
          });
          //Resolve all promisein our array
          Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
            console.log('Database Cleaned !');
          });
        });
    }

    return {
      get: function(){
        if (!instance){
          instance = new Database();
        }
        return instance;
      }
    }

  })();
```

**Do some action**

```
  //Create a database
  var DB = Database.get();

  function add(){
    var value = document.querySelector('#value').value;

    var obj = {
      title: value
    };
    //Add obj to our database
    DB.add(obj);
  }

  function reset(){
    //Reset our database
    DB.reset();
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="value">
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="add()">add</button>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="reset()">Destory database</button>
<div class="preview">
</div>
```

I think that **PouchDB** is a really good stuff, if you have time, fell free to test it :)

Comment: PouchDB is wonderful, but leaves the OP with his original question, which was is there some easy way to rewrite his synchronous code against an asynchronous library.

Comment: When using indexdb, be aware of browser comparability, IE10 is minimum. May our may not be a concern depending on your target audience.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is any way that make these method synchronous

No. Asynchronous methods are asynchronous because they are well, asynchronous. You cannot make something that is going to happen tomorrow (or 100ms from now) instead happen now.

What you really want is a way to write asynchronous code in such a way that it sort of looks like synchronous code. That will be both more readable, and in your case, will make adapting your code easier.

We want to somehow be able to write

```
A() . then(B);
```

as

```
A();
B();
```

and have it mean the same thing: to wait for A to finish before executing B. If a variable or result is involved, then we want to be able to write

```
A() . then(function(a) { return B(a+1); })
```

as

```
var a = A();
B(a+1);
```

#### Async functions

It turns out there **is** a way to do this: **async functions**. This feature is by no means available in all environments, but it's easy enough to find ways to access it. To use an async function, I put the keyword `async` in front of the `function`, then use the special keyword `await`. So the code above becomes just:

```
async function foo() {
  var a = await A();
  await B(a+1);
}
```

To get this to work, transpile your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), selecting the options for enabling async functions. Babel will translate your code into ES5, the kind of JavaScript all browsers know how to interpret.

The above code will actually return a promise that you can either hang a `then` from, or use in another async function:

```
async function bar() {
  await foo();
}
```

In your specific case:

```
async function write(contents) {
  await storage.setContents('docKey', contents);
  alert('doc created/updated');
}
```

#### Generators

There is another approach you might like to know about. It uses "generators", which are a special type of function in ES6 which "return" a value, but maintain their state, and can be called again and return more values after doing stuff in between. Generators are written like this, with an `*` after the function name:

```
function* foo() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
}
```

This function is called in a special way. First, you call it as `foo()` to make a thing called an **iterator**, and then you use the `next` method of the iterator to get the next value. (There are also other ways to retrieve the sequence of values, which we won't go into here.)

These generators can be used to write the kind of "asynchronous-but-looks-synchronous" code you want, as follows:

```
function* foo() {
  var a = yield A();
  yield B(a+1);
}
```

The code looks quite similar to the async function, but with `yield` replacing `await`.

But in this case, unlike the async functions described above, we need someone or something to ask for the first value, then wait for the promise returned by `yield` to resolve, then ask for the second value, and so on. The code do do so is not long, but is a bit complex. There are many libraries and utilities which do exactly that. For instance, a well-known one is called [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co). With `co`, you can write code which behaves identically to the async function I showed earlier as follows:

```
var foo = co.wrap(function* foo() {
  var a = yield A();
  yield B(a+1);
});
```

One reason for adopting this approach would be that generators are standard in ES6 and more widely available than async functions, which are being considered for ES7.